# Find if any element is present in System.Array or not and if exists remove from the original

Tags: c#, arrays, string-comparison

I have three System.Array where I store basically phone numbers with 10 characters. The definition is this:

```
private static System.Array objRowAValues;
private static System.Array objRowBValues;
private static System.Array objRowCValues;
```

I do this because I read a huge Excel file with many cells (around 1 000 000) and process with `List<string>` is a bit slow. Later in my code I change the System.Array to a `List<string>` mainly because I fill a ListBox elements. These are the definition for the List

```
private List<string> bd = new List<string>();
private List<string> bl = new List<string>();
private List<string> cm = new List<string>();
```

I want to check if any values in objRowAValues exists in objRowBValues or in objRowCValues and if exists then remove the existent value, how can I do this? I'm newbiew with C# and this is my first steps.

**EDIT: here is the code (relevant parts only) of what I'm doing:**

```
private List<string> bd = new List<string>();
private static System.Array objRowAValues;

private List<string> bl = new List<string>();
private static System.Array objRowBValues;

private List<string> cm = new List<string>();
private static System.Array objRowCValues;

private List<string> pl = new List<string>(); 

private static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application appExcel;

Excel.Application xlApp;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
Excel.Range rngARowLast, rngBRowLast, rngCRowLast;

long lastACell, lastBCell, lastCCell, fullRow;

// this is the main method I use to load all three Excel files and fill System.Array and then convert to List<string>

private void btnCargarExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(openFileDialog1.FileName))
            {
                Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
                stopWatch.Start();
                Thread.Sleep(10000);

                filePath.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString();

                xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(openFileDialog1.FileName, 0, true, 5, "", "", true,
                                                  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false,
                                                  false, 0, true, 1, 0);
                xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet) xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

                fullRow = xlWorkSheet.Rows.Count;
                lastACell = xlWorkSheet.Cells[fullRow, 1].End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row;
                rngARowLast = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "A" + lastACell);
                objRowAValues = (System.Array) rngARowLast.Cells.Value;

                foreach (object elem in objRowAValues) { bd.Add(cleanString(elem.ToString(), 10)); }

                nrosProcesados.Text = bd.Count().ToString();
                listBox1.DataSource = bd;

                xlWorkBook.Close(true, null, null);
                xlApp.Quit();

                releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
                releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
                releaseObject(xlApp);

                stopWatch.Stop();

                TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
                executiontime.Text =
                    String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
                                  ts.Milliseconds/10).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No se pudo abrir el fichero!");
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(appExcel);
                appExcel = null;
                System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
            }
        }
    }

    // This is the method where I clean the existent values from bd (the List where I should remove existent values on bl and existent values on cm
   private void btnClean_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pl = bd;
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(10000);

        pl.RemoveAll(element => bl.Contains((element)));
        pl.RemoveAll(element => cm.Contains((element)));

        textBox2.Text = pl.Count.ToString();
        listBox4.DataSource = pl;

        stopWatch.Stop();

        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
        textBox6.Text =
            String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
                          ts.Milliseconds / 10).ToString();

    }
```

Comment: If you need variable sized collections, don't use arrays. Use generic lists - [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/6sh2ey19.aspx), for example. I also suggest reading up about [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx).

Comment: @Oded I edited the post, see if that is what you refer on your comment and what can I do with LINQ?

Comment: Well, that's a start. As for LINQ - why not read the introduction that is on the link I posted?

Comment: @Oded I'm reading already and it's nice so using LINQ I can move for the objRowAValues but my question here is: how I can check if the value is present in objRowBValues and in objRowCValues and if exists then remove from the original objRowAValues? I'm coming from PHP and there exists a function called in_array() where I pass the element to find and the array to look for and the function returns TRUE on success or FALSE if not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two problems actually:

1. How to find in a performance effective way that a value exists in a (huge) collection?
2. How to remove value from a collection which is being enumerated?

For first one I recommend using `HashSet`, as `Contains` operation for it takes O(1) instead of O(n) for `List` / `Array`.

Second one is a bit tricky - instead of iterating through first collection, you can iterate through the rest and just try to remove that items from the first collection.

In case of `Hashset`, `Remove` includes `Contains` logic and returns `bool` to indicate if value was in collection, so it's easier to use `HashSet` for first collection also.

So it should looks like it:

```
    var a = new HashSet<string>();

    // OR, if you have existing array:
    // var a = new HashSet<string>(myArray);

    var b = new HashSet<string>();
    var c = new HashSet<string>();

    // ... some filling logic here ...

    foreach (var item in b)
    {
        a.Remove(item);
    }

    foreach (var item in c)
    {
        a.Remove(item);
    }
```

after that you can use `ToList()` to bind values to your control - it will create new array with all non-removed values:

```
    List<string> aList = a.ToList();
```

Comment: I will remove existent values from a List not from b or c as you do in your code, I tough unless I'm missing totally, could you please post a example doing this? (removing values from **a**) also check my previous comment about fill ListBox with values

Comment: Updated post to answer your questions.

Comment: Nice man, it took just 00:01:23.39 minutes in a PC with less resources (AMD A4 and 8GB DDR3 RAM at office) more less than 26 minutes in the other PC, it's working now, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Building on the comments on the OP, here is what you will want to do:

```
...make your lists...
bd.removeAll(phoneNum => bl.contains(phoneNum) || cm.contains(phoneNum));
```

Note that you *should not* be using `arrays`. You *should* instead be using `List<string>` for all three of the above.

Comment: I don't follow you :-( suppose that I want to remove the values from only **bd** so using LINQ I can do something like ` foreach (elem in bd) { bl.removeAll(i=>i == elem); }` is that right?

Comment: I have also updated with better variable names to make the solution more clear

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they are List and you want to discard elements only in `bd`, since you didn't state clearly from which lists should be deleted I would do it like this:

```
bd.RemoveAll(element => bl.Contains((element)));
bd.RemoveAll(element => cm.Contains((element)));
```

Or you could try using `HashSet`

```
private List<string> hsA = new List<string>();
private List<string> hsB = new List<string>();
private List<string> hsC = new List<string>();
```

And try using the same approach:

```
hsA.RemoveWhere(element => hsB.Contains(element) || hsC.Contains(element));
```

Comment: this approach seems to be fine but it's slow for a PC with a Core i3 550 and 12 GB of DDR3 so when it runs in a PC with less resources it will crash all. See this image http://dropmocks.com/mBsHrd for more information about

Comment: It takes 00:26:51.98 minutes to process the operations xD

Comment: I edited my answer providing a different approach that might be quicker.

Comment: Ok, @areks, bd is defined as a `List<string>` (see first post) but when I try to complete `bd.RemoveWhere` I have no reference to this method, why?

Comment: I know, that's why I suggest you to use HashSet instead of List<string> to check if you improve the performance.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you know how many rows you have try initializing the List with an appropriate maximum size. So it does not have to resize the underlying array constantly. Or use type save arrays `string[]` to save you some trouble with casting etc.

If you want to filter the RowAValues list you can do it with Linq:

```
rowAValues = rowAValues.Where(x => !rowBValues.Contains(x) 
                                && !rowCValues.Contains(x))
                       .ToArray()
```

Replace ToArray with ToList if you are using lists of course.

Keep in mind that iterating over thousands of items is quite performance intensive. If the check is executed more than once consider using a `HashSet<string>` for rows b+c. The code stays the same but the lookup will be lightening fast.

A good reference for LINQ (language integrated query) is http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: I don't know how many values the array will have because one day the Excel could have only 700 cells but another could have 700 000 or another could have 7 000 000 so for this reason I declare List<T> as I do and as for use `HashSet` for B and C only using in comparison and nothing else could be but then how I can fill a the ListBox with values from **rowBValues** and **rowCValues**? ListBox.DataSource only accepts List<string> any advice on this?